# Generate a dual axis graph for 2 different columns

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that looks like :

```
Date       val  var_1
01/09/2019  1   0.285
01/09/2019  1   0.27
01/09/2019  1   0.26
01/09/2019  2   0.295
01/09/2019  1   0.28
01/09/2019  1   0.295
01/09/2019  3   0.205
01/09/2019  4   0.12
01/09/2019  1   0.285
01/09/2019  1   0.3
01/09/2019  5   0.005
01/09/2019  1   0.285
01/09/2019  3   0.225
01/09/2019  3   0.23
01/09/2019  1   0.285
01/09/2019  2   0.26
01/09/2019  1   0.285
01/09/2019  1   0.25
01/09/2019  2   0.26
01/09/2019  2   0.26
01/09/2019  2   0.265
01/09/2019  0   0.325
01/09/2019  0   0.34
01/09/2019  0   0.35
01/09/2019  0   0.395
```

I generated column var_1 by using the formula :

```
=IF(K2=5,(RAND()*0.2+1.8),IF(K2=4,(RAND()*0.2+1.6),IF(K2=3,(RAND()*0.1+1.5),IF(OR(K2=2,K2=1),(RAND()*0.1+1.4),IF(K2=0,(RAND()*0.2+1.2),"NA")))))
```

WHERE K2 = val

what I am trying to do is that more the val is greater, less will be the var_1.

After generating this, I want to plot this on the dual axis graph in excel. Since we have a dual axis, it would create a graph like this(Note this is just the example):

[image]

Since if val is increasing signifies that var_1 is decreasing and vice versa.

Can anyone help me in understand how to plot the graph?

**EDIT**

Posting the image for excel in mac

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the two `val` columns, insert a *Line Chart* as shown below:

[image: Demo]

Click somewhere within the chart, go to the `Design` tab, then go to `Change Chart Type`, go to the last option **Combo**, set both chart type to `Line` but check the `Secondary Axis` box for `val_1` as shown above.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you however, I am using latest excel on mac and I am not able to get the dialogue box. Can you please help with that

Comment: I can see the design tabs, when I go for the combo, it has only 3 options there(first 3 as shown in your dialogue box.) Also I am not able to open dialogue box there.

Comment: I have added the image in the question itself under edit. can you take a look

Comment: @vp7 how about right click somewhere within the chart to find the `Change Chart Type...` option? I am not using Excel in Mac so cannot test it. Let me know how you go. P.s. you should mention in your post that what version of Excel (and in what OS) you are using.

Comment: My apologies for not mentioning the version of excel. However, I was able to solve it by clicking on a series and then format data series.